# SerialPort First Command OK. Second Command Error

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm writing a serialport app to talk to a Bluetooth module over serial port.  The first `At` command I send to the device runs fine and I get a response of the module version.  All subsequent commands fail with a response of ERROR.

Part of the code is here:

```
namespace PhoneApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //SerialPort myport = OPenPort.OpenIt();
        SerialPort myport = new SerialPort();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myport.PortName = "COM3";
            myport.BaudRate = 115200;
            myport.Parity = Parity.None;
            myport.DataBits = 8;
            myport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            myport.NewLine = System.Environment.NewLine;
            myport.ReadTimeout = 500;
            myport.WriteTimeout = 500;
            myport.DtrEnable = false;
            myport.RtsEnable = false;
            myport.WriteBufferSize = 4096;
            myport.ReadBufferSize = 4096;
            myport.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            myport.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;

            if (!myport.IsOpen)
            {                
                myport.Open();
            }

            calling.Visible = false;
            myport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
            mycommand.Text = @"AT+BGVER";
```

the button which sends the command. The device requires a newline after each comand.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {               
        myport.WriteLine(mycommand.Text.Trim());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Can you communicate with the device using a terminal program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. i found the problem. In fact I had to use myport.Write instead of myport.WriteLine. I deleted the line myport.NewLine and I appended "\r" to every command. Now the device responds as expected. As for DTR and RTS they are not required by the device according to the vendor

Comment: Or you could just set `.NewLine = "\r";` and continue to use `.WriteLine`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your problem, but I noticed that you don't have flow control enabled (e.g. `myport.RtsEnable = false; myport.DtrEnable = false;`).

Have you checked the documentation to make sure that the Bluetooth module doesn't require it?  Typically devices with 115kbps and higher need flow control.

Another thing to check is the NewLine constant.  You set it to the sys default which is likely Cr+Lf.  Make sure that the module expects that.

Comment: I'd agree that DTR should be on, but RTS is device dependent.  Try it and see.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. i found the problem. In fact I had to use myport.Write instead of myport.WriteLine. I deleted the line myport.NewLine and I appended "\r" to every command. Now the device responds as expected. As for DTR and RTS they are not required by the device according to the vendor.